# Error after adding YahooSDK

Tags: ios, xcode, yahoo-api

I am using this [YahooSDK](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc) to develop a project.

The demo app within this project works fine. But whenever I try to add `YahooSDK` folder into my project I get errors.

`No type or protocol named 'UIWebViewDelegate'`,
`Unknown type name 'UIWebView'`, `Unknown type name 'UIViewController'`

Theses errors are not shown in the original project. Does this have to do something with Xcode versions? I'm using 7.1 .

Comment: Hi rishab, do you know how can i fetch all the contact list of Yahoo in swift ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: but this application got crashed after success of login

Comment: Hi @Rishab do you have any idea that why Demo application got crashed first time?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to import UIKit header.

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in `YahooSession.h` file.

This will fix your problem.

Comment: i made it with swift 3, Follow my link https://github.com/amitdagar/YahooLogin_ContactList